# Which System Call provides an interface for sending messages to devices?

Tags: system-calls

Question is above. I've looked through the man pages, but they are somewhat unclear on the topic. I'm not sure if I'm looking for sendmsg() or msgsend() or if I'm looking for something totally different

Comment: What kind of devices are you considering? Please give a few examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devices are usually represented as [device files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) in Linux - they can be read from and written to just like any other file. For example, the first hard disk in the system is usually represented as `/dev/sda` - you directly read from it, and you can also directly write to it (for example with `dd` to create or restore a disk image).

For other purposes that can't be represented as reading/writing, for example talking to the SMART interface of a hard disk, [ioctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl)s are used.